# Metric tensor under diffeomorphisms

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, diffeomorphism-invariance

It's probably a stupid question but I can't understand where I am wrong.

I have a manifold with metric $g(X,Y)$ and I know that under infinitesimal diffeomorphism ($x'^\mu = x^\mu + \varepsilon^\mu$) the components of the metric have to transform as
$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{dx'^\sigma}{dx^\mu}\frac{dx'^\rho}{dx^\nu}g'_{\sigma\rho}
$$
so that the metric tensor $g = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is left invariant (the metric tensor $g$ is the same in all local maps, and the components $g_{\mu\nu}$ relative to different maps can be mapped one into another with the above diffeormophispm). Therefore, plugging my equation for the infinitesimal diffeomorphism $x'^\mu = x^\mu + \varepsilon^\mu$, I get
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = (\delta_\mu^\sigma + \partial_\mu \varepsilon^\sigma)(\delta_\nu^\rho + \partial_\nu \varepsilon^\rho)(g_{\sigma\rho}+\partial_\tau g_{\sigma\rho}\varepsilon^\tau) = g_{\mu\nu}+L_\varepsilon (g_{\mu\nu}) \; \rightarrow\; L_\epsilon(g_{\mu\nu}) = 0
$$
But I know that under diffeomorphisms the metric tensor components should transform as
$$
g'_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu}+L_\varepsilon(g_{\mu\nu})
$$
So I should have $L_\varepsilon(g_{\mu\nu})\neq 0 $ in general, but why? And how can I obtain the above formula?

Comment: The metric is not invariant but covariant, so the (components) do not satisfy $g_{\mu \nu} = g_{\mu \nu}^{,}$. You have the correct transformation law above.

Comment: I think what your question is more about isometries than diffeomorfisms. And what you might be looking for is the Killing vector field condition which reads $\mathcal{L}_X(g)=0$ being $X = \epsilon^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}$ the Killing vector field in your example.  If $X$ is not a Killing vector field (no isometry) then the isomorfism is not and isometry. Not sure I helped.

Comment: The metric $g(X,Y)$ is a scalar and thus invariant. The only mapping between manifolds that preserves the metric tensor components is the identity map.

Comment: @Eletie The metric tensor $g=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is invariant under change of coordinates, the components of such tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ are the ones which are covariant, and indeed I wrote the trasformation relations for covariant components. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: @PhysicsKoan This is exactly what I said, so the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_{\epsilon} g_{\mu \nu}$ should *not* vanish in general

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus the metric is a tensor, it *defines* the inner product which you wrote $g(X,Y)$, which is its contraction with two vectors.

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA. Indeed you are right, I know that the condition $L_\varepsilon (g_{\mu\nu}) = 0\;\rightarrow\; \nabla_{(a}\varepsilon_{b)}=0$ is the condition for a Killing vector (so it should be more stringent than just diffeomorphism). Indeed if I take my last equation $g'_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} + L_\varepsilon (g_{\mu\nu})$ and I request my metric components to be unchanged then I correctly obtain $L_\varepsilon(g_{\mu\nu}) )=0$ (this makes sense to me), but I don't understand why I get this same result just asking for diffeomorphism invariance.

Comment: @Eletie I agree with you, but I don't understand why it vanishes in my calculations, I know it shouldn't, but I can't find where I made a mistake

Comment: It doesn't vanish. You shouldn't be requiring the metric to be invariant. You're calculating the components, which are diffeomorphism *covariant* not invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have the metric $g$ in some coordinates $x^\mu$ is given by
\begin{equation}
g = g_{\mu\nu}(x)\mathrm{d}x^\mu \otimes \mathrm{d}x^\nu
\end{equation}
As you are correcly saying the tensor $g$ is independent of the coordinates you choose for spacetime, thus if you pick different coordinates $x^{\prime\mu}$ you have
\begin{equation}
g = g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x^\prime)\mathrm{d}x^{\prime\mu} \otimes \mathrm{d}x^{\prime\nu}
\end{equation}
The differential transforms as
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}x^{\prime\mu} = \frac{\partial x^{\prime\mu}}{\partial x^\nu}\mathrm{d}x^\nu
\end{equation}
thus you get
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}(x) = \frac{\partial x^{\prime\lambda}}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^{\prime\sigma}}{\partial x^\nu}g^\prime_{\lambda\sigma}(x^\prime)
\end{equation}
as you correctly write. Now let us consider infinitesimal coordinate transformations $x^{\prime\mu} = x^\mu - \epsilon^\mu(x)$ we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial x^{\prime\lambda}}{\partial x^\mu} = {\delta^\lambda}
_\mu -\frac{\partial \epsilon^\lambda}{\partial x^\mu}
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}(x) = g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x^\prime) - \frac{\partial \epsilon^\lambda}{\partial x^\mu} g^\prime_{\lambda\nu}(x^\prime) -
\frac{\partial \epsilon^\sigma}{\partial x^\nu} g^\prime_{\mu\sigma}(x^\prime) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\end{equation}
note they evaluated at different points. The Lie derivative is basically the variation
\begin{equation}
\delta g_{\mu\nu} = g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x) - g_{\mu\nu}(x)
\end{equation}
note they are evaluated at the same point. We have
\begin{equation}
g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x^\prime) = g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x) - \epsilon^\lambda \frac{\partial g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\partial x^\lambda} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\end{equation}
thus
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}(x) = g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x) - \epsilon^\lambda \frac{\partial g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\partial x^\lambda} - \frac{\partial \epsilon^\lambda}{\partial x^\mu} g^\prime_{\lambda\nu}(x) -
\frac{\partial \epsilon^\sigma}{\partial x^\nu} g^\prime_{\mu\sigma}(x) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\end{equation}
And you get
\begin{equation}
\delta g_{\mu\nu}(x) = \mathcal{L}_\epsilon g_{\mu\nu} = \epsilon^\lambda \frac{\partial g^\prime_{\mu\nu}(x)}{\partial x^\lambda} + \frac{\partial \epsilon^\lambda}{\partial x^\mu} g^\prime_{\lambda\nu}(x) +
\frac{\partial \epsilon^\sigma}{\partial x^\nu} g^\prime_{\mu\sigma}(x)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I used to get confused over this stuff too in the past